# ¿Cómo leer todos los elementos de un arraylist?

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<plato> nombres=new ArrayList<plato>();

public void menu() {
    nombres.add((new plato("cerdo", false, 800, tiposDeCarne.Carne_Roja)));
    nombres.add(new plato("vacuno", false, 700, tiposDeCarne.Carne_Roja));
    nombres.add(new plato("pollo", false, 400, tiposDeCarne.Carne_Roja));
    nombres.add(new plato("papas fritas", true, 530, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("arroz", true, 800, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("tuti fruti", true, 120, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("pizza", true, 550, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("camarones", false, 300, tiposDeCarne.Pescado_Y_Mariscos));
    nombres.add(new plato("salmon", false, 450, tiposDeCarne.Pescado_Y_Mariscos));
    nombres.add(new plato("chuletas", false, 900, tiposDeCarne.Carne_Roja));
    nombres.add(new plato("bistec", false, 650, tiposDeCarne.Carne_Roja));
    nombres.add(new plato("escalopas de pollo", false, 500, tiposDeCarne.Carne_Roja));
    nombres.add(new plato("pure", true, 450, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("lentejas", true, 300, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("ensalada", true, 100, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("chorrilana", false, 950, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("atun", false, 350, tiposDeCarne.Pescado_Y_Mariscos));
    nombres.add(new plato("almejas", false, 220, tiposDeCarne.Pescado_Y_Mariscos));
    nombres.add(new plato("jamon", false, 600, tiposDeCarne.Carne_Roja));
    nombres.add(new plato("costillar", false, 700, tiposDeCarne.Carne_Roja));
    nombres.add(new plato("hamburguesa de pollo", false, 890, tiposDeCarne.Carne_Roja));
    nombres.add(new plato("porotos", true, 530, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("quinoa", true, 230, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("duraznos", true, 600, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("hotdog", false, 800, tiposDeCarne.Otra));
    nombres.add(new plato("cochayuyo", true, 120, tiposDeCarne.Pescado_Y_Mariscos));
    nombres.add(new plato("mariscal", false, 450, tiposDeCarne.Pescado_Y_Mariscos));

     this.leer();
}

public void leer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < nombres.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(nombres.get(i));
    System.out.println("\n");
    }


  }
}
```

El método `leer` solo me lee el ultimo elemento (valga la redundancia) osea: 
 "mariscal,false,450,tipocarne..."

¿Quizás tenga que ocupar otro tipo de arrays?

Comment: hola @mengano, agrega tu objeto plato

Comment: gracias por las respuestas ...luego de analizar todas las clases me di cuenta que los atributos de la clase plato tenian un static por eso siempre me devolvia el ultimo objecto agregado :p

Comment: @mengano creo que habra mucha gente que querra matarte en este momento... :p

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de la función "leer", debes iterar los elementos del ArrayLisit de esta forma:

```
for(Object[] obj : nombres){
    System.out.print(obj[0].toString());        
}
```

Comment: porque su funcion no anda, si aunque no lo creas, for(obj foo: bar) se expande exactamente a lo que escribio?

Answer (score 1):

Una forma es obtener cada objeto del `ArrayList` mediante un bucle y obtener la propiedad mediante el "getter" creado en tu objeto `plato` para imprimir su valor.

En este ejemplo suponiendo tienes en tu objeto el método `getNombre()` para obtener el nombre del objeto.

```
public void leer() {

    for (plato p nombres) {
        System.out.print(p.getNombre());
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

}
```

---

Otra forma es sobrescribir el método `toString()` en tu objeto `plato`, y ahí agregar las propiedades que deseas imprimir.

Ejemplo :

```
class plato {

    ...
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  nombre + ", " + precio;
    }

}
```

de esta forma simplemente llama el método

```
 public void leer() {

        for (plato p nombres) {
            System.out.print(p.toString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes sobrescribir el metodo toString() dentro del objeto Plato:

```
@Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Plato{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", bandera=" + bandera + ", precio=" + precio + ", tipo_carne=" + tipo_carne + '}';
        }
```

Esto es para obtener una cadena completa de las propiedades del objeto.

Para recorrer el "ArrayList nombres" Puedes utilizar un for o foreach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nombres.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(nombres.get(i).toString());
        }
```

Comment: pero este es el codigo que OP escribio. no entiendo la diferencia

Comment: Recuerda evitar realizar varias respuestas, revisa [answer].

Comment: Indico que se sobreescriba el metodo toString ya que no añadio el pojo "plato" y podría ser que no este el metodo toString.

Comment: Pero OP dice que siempre muestra el ultimo. no que muestre otra cosa. Tal vez su codigo ande y OP piense que no?

Answer (score -1):

Prueba esto:

```
for(plato pl: nombres){
      System.out.println(pl.toString());
 }
```

Comment: Y esto como ayud al problema? Responde sólo con código se considera de baja calidad

Answer (score -2):

Espero sea lo que buscas y Saludos.

```
  package com.itsoft.hope.testeraakeapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Adrian Alonso Ake Ek
 */
public class LeerClase {

    private ArrayList<Plato> nombres = new ArrayList<Plato>();
    public static final String CARNE_ROJA = "Carne Roja";
    public static final String OTRA = "Otra";
    public static final String PESCADO_Y_MARISCOS = "Pescado_Y_Mariscos";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LeerClase lc = new LeerClase();
        lc.menu();
    }

    public void menu() {
        nombres.add((new Plato("cerdo", false, 800, LeerClase.CARNE_ROJA)));
        nombres.add(new Plato("vacuno", false, 700, LeerClase.CARNE_ROJA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("pollo", false, 400, LeerClase.CARNE_ROJA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("papas fritas", true, 530, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("arroz", true, 800, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("tuti fruti", true, 120, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("pizza", true, 550, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("camarones", false, 300, LeerClase.PESCADO_Y_MARISCOS));
        nombres.add(new Plato("salmon", false, 450, LeerClase.PESCADO_Y_MARISCOS));
        nombres.add(new Plato("chuletas", false, 900, LeerClase.CARNE_ROJA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("bistec", false, 650, LeerClase.CARNE_ROJA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("escalopas de pollo", false, 500, LeerClase.CARNE_ROJA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("pure", true, 450, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("lentejas", true, 300, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("ensalada", true, 100, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("chorrilana", false, 950, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("atun", false, 350, LeerClase.PESCADO_Y_MARISCOS));
        nombres.add(new Plato("almejas", false, 220, LeerClase.PESCADO_Y_MARISCOS));
        nombres.add(new Plato("jamon", false, 600, LeerClase.CARNE_ROJA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("costillar", false, 700, LeerClase.CARNE_ROJA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("hamburguesa de pollo", false, 890, LeerClase.CARNE_ROJA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("porotos", true, 530, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("quinoa", true, 230, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("duraznos", true, 600, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("hotdog", false, 800, LeerClase.OTRA));
        nombres.add(new Plato("cochayuyo", true, 120, LeerClase.PESCADO_Y_MARISCOS));
        nombres.add(new Plato("mariscal", false, 450, LeerClase.PESCADO_Y_MARISCOS));

        this.leer();
    }

    public void leer() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nombres.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(nombres.get(i).toString());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }

    class Plato {

        private String nombre;
        private boolean bandera;
        private Integer precio;
        private String tipo_carne;

        public Plato() {
        }

        public Plato(String nombre, boolean bandera, Integer precio, String tipo_carne) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.bandera = bandera;
            this.precio = precio;
            this.tipo_carne = tipo_carne;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public boolean isBandera() {
            return bandera;
        }

        public void setBandera(boolean bandera) {
            this.bandera = bandera;
        }

        public Integer getPrecio() {
            return precio;
        }

        public void setPrecio(Integer precio) {
            this.precio = precio;
        }

        public String getTipo_carne() {
            return tipo_carne;
        }

        public void setTipo_carne(String tipo_carne) {
            this.tipo_carne = tipo_carne;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Plato{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", bandera=" + bandera + ", precio=" + precio + ", tipo_carne=" + tipo_carne + '}';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que has cambiado? donde estaba el problema? como lo has solucionado? por que estaba mal? Deberías explicar todo esto en la respuesta.

Comment: ademas, esta respuesta incluye un monton de codigo que la original no tiene.. de donde salio?

Comment: No publiques múltiples respuestas, deja una edítala y elimina la otra